# Count reccuring names in a column

Tags: count, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I have this spreadsheet with all the movies I've seen during 2015. 
I want to find an easy way to count the actors names (in column G) and print the most common names, with both the name and number of times it occurs.

Can I do that?

Here is the spreadsheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jO6OTLRYW3-id6SynkNBeFSpYshZ_lTUWam3mS8CaKw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Apps, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your column data ► Data ► Pivot Table...

Then in the "Rows - Add Field" add your column name.

Finally, in the "Values - Add Field" add the same column and choose `COUNTA`.

This might be your desired set-up:
[image]

Comment: Awesome, that was easy. Thanks!